# Getting errors when dictionary value is in unicode

Tags: python, json, csv, unicode

I am making a python code that will be run on a server that converts an JSON file into an csv. (JSON supplied via url)

Everything is going well except when the value of a key is a unicode.

Like this:

```
{u'name':u'\xc3\x86\xc3\x9f\xc3\xb8\xc3\xa4\xc3\xae\xc3\xa8t\xc3\xae\xc3\xbf' , u'otherinfo' : u'info'}
```

Which gives this error: `UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-11: ordinal not in range(128)`

I understand that python tries to decode the unicode but fails, but I do not know how to solve this problem.

This is what I have so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python  
import urllib2 as url
import json
import ast

print("Extracting data from API")
request = url.Request('url')
data = url.urlopen(request).read()
data = data.decode("iso-8859-1")
print("changed")
data = ast.literal_eval(data)
data = json.dumps(data)



import json, csv

outfile = open("output.csv", "w")
fieldnames = ['names','otherinfo']
writer = csv.DictWriter(outfile , fieldnames=fieldnames, lineterminator='\n' )

print("Writing csv file")
row = json.loads(data)
for player in row["rows"]:
    print(player)
    writer.writerow(player)



outfile.close()

print("Writing complete")
```

Comment: Try changing `"iso-8859-1"` to `"utf8"`.

Comment: Use `json.loads(data.encode('utf-8'))`

Comment: What about using `unicode_escape` instead of `iso-8859-1`?

Comment: Still coming up with the same error unfortunately even after changing json.loads(data.encode('utf-8')
However the name is changed to "u'\xc6\xdf\xf8\xe4\xee\xe8t\xee\xff'"